# Is there any clear() function in swing like clear() function in JavaScript

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

Is there any function in swing like clear() function in JavaScript. I want to clear all field data like textField, comboBox and textArea when I pressed clear button.

To clear all fields I have to write code for every field like this.

```
void clearFields() {
    txtName.setText("");
    txtNo.setText("");
    bModify.setEnabled(false);
    bSave.setEnabled(true);
}
```

if I have like 20 components, then I have to write 20 line of code. Instead of this if I have this function like clear(), I could use simply.

Comment: Short answer is no. It's doable, but how deep into the container hierarchy do you want to dig?

Comment: *"..like clear() function in HTML."*  HTML does not have any functions. Are you thinking of JavaScript?

Comment: The simplest method is to set an `onClick` listener to your `clear button`, then set the `textField` to an empty string.

Comment: Sounds like this is more an architectural problem: Why do your views/controls hold data? With proper separation of concerns (MVC), your views only display data. Clearing is then simple (clear data in the model).

Comment: @Scar A more practical, long term, reusable solution would be to use ActionListenet, the you include key board users as well

Comment: I think repaintng the panal may be workout

Comment: I asked a similar question in here and could not find a short way to do this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800180/reset-jcomponent-to-default-value

Comment: i think using method only be a good practice